# Autofac DI in Using statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, console-application, autofac

I have an Update method in my class which contains a using statement to create a new instance of UnitOfWork, this is because I'm sending emails asynchronously and as EF and DbContext are not thread safe have to create a new dbContext for each request. 
I have used Autofac for DI in my UnitOfWork however I don't know how to use my new UnitOfWork constructor in using statement to make sure it creates a new instance.
Please note that this is a console application.
Thanks

UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private IEventLoggerService MailCheckerLog;
    private readonly BBEntities ctx = new BBEntities();
    private IEmailRepository emailRepository;

    public UnitOfWork(IEventLoggerService MaLog, IEmailRepository emailRepo)
    {
        emailRepository = emailRepo;
        MailCheckerLog = MaLog;
    }

    public IEmailRepository EmailRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.emailRepository == null)
            {
                this.emailRepository = new EmailRepository(ctx);
            }
            return emailRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            this.ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MailCheckerLog.log("Unit Of Work Exception => Commit() => " + e.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }

}
```

EmailService.cs

```
    public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {

        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private IEventLoggerService MailCheckerLog;
        private ISMTPService SMTPService;

        public EmailService(IEventLoggerService Log, IUnitOfWork uOfWork, ISMTPService SMTPS)
        {
            unitOfWork = uOfWork;
            MailCheckerLog = Log;
            SMTPService = SMTPS;
            SMTPService.OnMailSendComplete += new EventHandler(SendCompletedC);
        }




        public void Update(tb_Email obj)
        {
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2;
            using (unitOfWork2 = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                unitOfWork2.EmailRepository.Update(obj);
                unitOfWork2.Commit();
            }
        }
}
```

**Updated:**

I got it working with the following solution however not sure if it is the best way

UnitOfWorkFactory.cs

```
public class UnitOfWorkFacotry : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{

    private IUnitOfWork uow;
    private IEmailRepository emailrepo;
    private IEventLoggerService eventlog;

    public UnitOfWorkFacotry(IEventLoggerService MaLog, IEmailRepository emailRep)
    {

        emailrepo = emailRep;
        eventlog = MaLog;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork GetCurrent()
    {
        return uow ?? create();
    }

    public IUnitOfWork create()
    {
        return new UnitOfWork(eventlog, emailrepo);
    }

}
```

EmailService.cs -> Update method

```
    public void Update(tb_Email obj)
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2;
        using (unitOfWork2 = unitOfWorkFactory.create())
        {
            unitOfWork2.EmailRepository.Update(obj);
            unitOfWork2.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ISMTPService` just a wrapper around the frameworks `SmtpClient`? If so you should know that you can't send multiple mails simultaneously even with the asynchronous methods, the code has to wait for each call/mail to complete before starting a new one. In short, if you want to use this library, you are better off using the synchronous methods.

Comment: Yes, as well as a method to send the email and an event.

Comment: But that's exactly what I needed and is working fine. The code send the emails to server and later it will raise and event if the sent was successful or not and base on that I use the update method to update the database.

Comment: (see the changed comment above). Alternatively you can use a different library like [mailkit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which is recommended in .net core (*as SmtpClient has been removed from .net core*).

Comment: @Igor - FYI - SmtpClient is only missing from .NET Core 1.x. It is available in .NET Core 2.x.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - Nice, thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't like the current implementation of the UoW and Repository pattern in your example, I think you can solve your issue by adding a method called `BeginTransaction()` or something similar.

This way you can just inject the `UnitOfWork`and start using it. This also gives you a bit more flexibility on when to start a transaction and add some extra logic in you methods perhaps.

In your case I think this should similar to the following code block.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDispose
{
    void BeginTransaction();
    void Commit();
}


public class EmailService : IEmailService
{

    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IEventLoggerService MailCheckerLog;
    private ISMTPService SMTPService;

    public EmailService(... IUnitOfWork unitOfWork ..)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        //Other stuff
    }

    public void Update(tb_Email obj)
    {
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2;
        using (unitOfWork2.BeginTransaction())
        {
            unitOfWork2.EmailRepository.Update(obj);
            unitOfWork2.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I'm more a fan of Derek Greer's suggestion (the `Unit of Work Decorator`) which he explains quite well in this post: https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/
This is a bit more complex compared to the 'regular' implementations, but much cleaner in my opinion. Not to promote my own blog, but I've written a [post](https://www.jan-v.nl/post/splitting-unit-of-work-and-repository-functionality) about this how to implement with Autofac.

The most important code of this post is this.

```
//Registration
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(IncomingFileHandler<>)).Named("commandHandler", typeof(IIncomingFileHandler<>));
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(IncomingFileHandlerTransactionDecorator<>), typeof(IIncomingFileHandler<>), fromKey: "commandHandler");

//The unit of work decorator
public class IncomingFileHandlerTransactionDecorator<TCommand> : IIncomingFileHandler<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : IncomingFileCommand
{
    private readonly IIncomingFileHandler<TCommand> decorated;
    private readonly IDbContext context;

    public IncomingFileHandlerTransactionDecorator(IIncomingFileHandler<TCommand> decorated, IDbContext context)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        using (var transaction = context.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                decorated.Handle(command)

                context.SaveChanges();
                context.Commit(transaction);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Rollback(transaction);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution? Also what is wrong with the UoW and repo pattern?

Comment: Thanks, I'm still confused about it, saw the article and it also mention that one other way is to create a UoW Factory, my questions is how can I pass my parameters (in Autofac) to the UoW constructor while I'm creating a new UoWFactory instance. My UoW needs at least one injected service which is the EventLoggerService.